# How do I get the id in the login?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How do I get the Id in the login?

I'm using entity framework and in the frmLogin I have this:

```
    private bool IsValidUser(string userName, string pass)
    {
        Context context = new Context();

        var query = (from c in context.Cuentas
                     where c.Nombre == userName && c.Password == pass
                     select c);

        return query.Any();
    }
```

but with this function, I can only verify if the user is in the Database.

I want to get the id of this user too.

Answer (score 2):

instead of the `if(query.Any())` .... try:

```
var user = query.FirstOrDefault();

if (user == null)
     return false;

var id = user.ID;
```

Comment: Wouldn't SingleOrDefault() be better? I'm assuming there shouldn't ever be more than one user where the username and password match.

Comment: Probably true -- if you don't mind it throwing an exception --- although have two records with matching username and passwords would definitely be an exception situation.  (username probably should be an unique index in the database)

Comment: I press F9 in the last line "var id = user.ID" and when I verify the id value, it takes "0"

Comment: maybe because int value is default set to 0...hmm? correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think is possible to have only one user with th same username :) => one username = one user

you can try this

```
var user = context.Cuentas.singleordefault(d=>d.userName==userName & d.password==password);
int id;
if (user!=null)
{
   id=user.userId;
   return true;
}
return false;
```

EDITED

Comment: Two comments: you are only looking at the userid if the password test fails -- you're more likely to need to user id it the password check succeeds, especially since if the password fails, you DO NOT CARE about this user (it could be a hacker, and any information you load about the user might reach him and aid in his hacking.)   Further, moved the password check from the database (which is highly optimized for such things) to code (which is not so optimized)

Comment: it works, but I have a global variable "public int cuentaId" and when I try to do this: "this.cuentaId = userId;" the value of "cuentaid" is 0 :S

Comment: missing brackets in if statement >> firstly i check password if provided pass equals with pass stored in db  and then set id to global variable and return true...it should correct the problem ...i think ...

Comment: "cuentaId" is the global variable, so I have cuentaId = user.Id and then i put return true, but still takes 0

Comment: add user to watchlist and you can add do this 
int id=-1;
if(user.password==password) 
   {
   id=user.Id;
   this.cuetanId=user.Id;
   return true;
}
and see if is int id different from -1
because maybe your user have ID 0 in database

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand. What is watchlist?

Comment: at first Sorry for my bad english
in Visual studio is functionality to watch variables, objects.. you can do it by right click on variable and there is add to watch list,  or you can just add breakpoint to line and stay with mouse over variable to see their value but if you have assigning command on line 9 add breakpoint to line 10 and then check value of your global cuetanId variable

Comment: yes, i added a breakpoint, but when i check the value, is 0. i don't know why :S

Comment: And what number you expect to be after request ?....
Try to initialize this.cuetanId to -1
you can try find function to see where you use this variable to chceck if you are not overwrite it

Comment: yes, i initialize cuentaId in -1, but when i check the line "this.cuentaId = user.id", cuentaid still value -1. :S

Comment: and what about user.id value ?...
i do not understand where can be problem

Comment: user.id is 2 and cuentaId is 0. the problem is that cuentaId isn't equal to user.id, i don't know why.

Comment: go through all code and check if you do not have line where can you overwrite variable

Comment: no, because is the only use of cuentaId. i declare "public int cuentaId". its ok?

Comment: I think is correct but try to change it to..
public static int cuentaId;...
access > classname.cuentaId if helps

Comment: still no works :S i don't know why because i think is correct the line "this.cuentaId = user.Id".

Comment: but if i create a local variable, int id = user.Id, its works. its a mysterious